# How to export doi links without description?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I want export a doi link from an org file to LaTeX and then to pdf. If the doi link has no description the export does not work. Why? I want as a result in pdf, not the description but the doi address.

```
    #+TITLE: Exporting doi link
    #+AUTHOR: SB
    #+Date: \today
    #+OPTIONS: H:3 toc:nil num:nil d:nil
    #+LATEX_CLASS: memarticle
    #+LATEX_CMD: xelatex

    * First

    This exports to \LaTeX: [[doi:10.1111/j.1468-0149.2007.00450_2.x][doi-description]] and this [[http:www.ine.pt]].

    But not a doi link with no description: [[doi:10.1111/j.1468-0149.2007.00450_2.x][]].
```

Comment: Your example works for me, although the second doi is wrapped in [[]] in the output. You can get rid of that by using the syntax  `[[doi:10.1111/j.1468-0149.2007.00450_2.x]]`. i.e., don't include the empty `[]` description field.

Comment: Yes it works only if I export it using `pandoc`. When I export using `C-c l o` I have to put something (a space) in the description field.

Comment: I'm exporting with `C-e l o` and it works as expected. What do you mean by 'working' and 'not working' - do you not see the link, or is the link improperly formatted or ??

Comment: Not working in this case means that the pdf is not produced. I examined the tex file that results in this case and I found this: `\href{http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1468-0149.2007.00450_2.x}{doi:%s10.1111/j.1468-0149.2007.00450_2.x}`. But if it is working for you I think that is a problem with `memarticle`.

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that I don't have memarticle, so I had to remove that line to get it to compile